# Using temp column to filter the results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My query is like this.

```
select id,name,salary,(salary-2000) AS [Deductedsalary]  
from EmployeeDetails
```

I want to use the [Deductedsalary] column in where clause, similar to below query.

```
select 
    id, name, salary, (salary-2000) AS [Deductedsalary]  
from 
    EmployeeDetails 
where 
    [Deductedsalary] > 5000
```

NOTE: I don't want to use filter query with 'salary' column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery to define the alias:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  salary-2000 as deducted_salary
        ,       *
        from 
                EmployeeDetails 
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   Deductedsalary > 5000
```

Comment: I just missed by some second... I had posted a similar answer. I will mark it as deleted :)

Comment: @ARS: You posted before me, actually.  You can hover over the time to get an exact timestamp (11:10:19 vs 11:10:00.)  If you undelete your answer, I'll vote it up :)

Comment: hey I didn't realised that. I have undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it directly - you'll have to either filter on the underlying `Salary` column, or use something like a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
   SELECT
       id, name, salary, 
       DeductedSalary = salary - 2000
   FROM
       dbo.EmployeeDetails 
)
SELECT 
   id, name, salary, DeductedSalary
FROM 
   CTE
WHERE
   [Deductedsalary] > 5000
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method would be

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       salary,
       DeductedSalary
FROM   EmployeeDetails
CROSS APPLY (SELECT salary-2000) DS(DeductedSalary)
WHERE  DeductedSalary > 5000
```

Though I'd use

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       salary,
       ( salary - 2000 ) AS [Deductedsalary]
FROM   EmployeeDetails
WHERE  [salary] > 7000
```

As this is sargable (can use an index and will have better cardinality estimates)

Comment: An index on salary would be rather unusual?  The question also says "I don't want to use filter query with 'salary' column"

Comment: @Andomar - Depends how frequently they need to run such queries as to whether it should be indexed. Avoiding unsargable expressions when there is an obvious sargable alternative is a best practice irrespective of what the OP says they want but I'll add another way to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
Select *
    FROM
    (
        select 
          id, name, salary, (salary-2000) AS [Deductedsalary]  
        from 
           EmployeeDetails 

    ) data
    where 
          [Deductedsalary] > 5000
```